# Disabling auto capture/release on vmware with open-vm-tools-desktop

Tags: vmware, vmware-player, vmware-workstation

I'm running an Ubuntu server as a guest (console only no X so no point for mouse) is there a way to only install vmhgfs-fuse package so I can share files from host to guest without installing full open-vm-tools-desktop?

If not, is there a way to DISABLE auto release/capture input? Since it's console only and running in a small 800x600 window, it's a pain to always focus mouse pointer inside the window and frequently I find that I'm typing on a host instead of a guest because I bumped the mouse.

Comment: I don't know about sharing files between guest/host without installing the guest utils however you can disable/enable input capture by going to Edit->Preferences->Input and then under "Cursor" uncheck "Ungrab when cursor leaves window". Another possible option, is to edit the .vmx file when the vm is powered off. Add or edit these lines to the vmx file `usb.generic.allowHID = "FALSE"
mouse.vusb.enable = "FALSE"
mouse.vusb.useBasicMouse = "FALSE"`. Note this may disable all HID devices not just the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

this bug report suggests its being moved to open-vm-tools package from the open-vm-tools-desktop , it also shows some attempts to do what you are asking.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/open-vm-tools/+bug/1551558

have you tried open-vm-tools ?

Comment: But as the comments say open-vm-tools doesn't contain Vmhgfs-fuse so can't share files with host?